# I do not understand this simple bandstop filter example

Tags: matlab, filters, bandwidth, digital-filters

I have a periodic signal like this one with period $T=120$:

[image]

I would like to apply a bandstop filter to the signal, the stop band should go from 90% of $\frac{1}{T}$ to 110% of $\frac{1}{T}$.

So I run this code in Octave

```
A=-ones(1,35);
B=ones(1,45);
C=-ones(1,20);
D=ones(1,20);
E=[A B C D];
x=repmat(E,[1 6]);

figure
plot(x,'b');
axis([1 numel(x) -1.5 1.5]);
title('Input signal');
print -dpng input.png


figure
plot(x,'b');
axis([1 numel(x) -1.5 1.5]);


signal_period=numel(E);
signal_frequency=1/signal_period;

sampling_period=1;
sampling_frequency=1/sampling_period;

% "The Nyquist frequency is half the sample rate",
% from http://it.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir1.html#inputarg_Wn
Nyquist_frequency=sampling_frequency/2;

signal_normalized_frequency = signal_frequency/Nyquist_frequency;

b = fir1(40,[0.9*signal_normalized_frequency 1.1*signal_normalized_frequency],'stop');
y = filter(b,1,x);

hold on
plot(y,'r');
title('Input (blue), output (red)');

print -dpng filter_response.png
```

and I get this filtered signal:

[image]

I would expect an attenuation of the signal but I only get a slightly "delayed" signal with some "ringing".

What am I missing?

My ideas:

1. I made a mistake in `fir1` with the definition of the lower and
   upper cutoff frequencies, perhaps I do not understand the normalized
   frequency concept?
2. Maybe the cutoff frequencies are too low? The frequency response of the filter is the following:[image] and I cannot see the classical "deep" stop band of a notch filter in the magnitude graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need the stopband to be very close to 0, which is hard to do; this is why your filter looks like a high-pass. There are two possibilities: reduce the sampling rate, so that `1/T` is not so close to 0, or increase the filter order.

I tried increasing the filter order with:

```
T = 120;
fN = 0.5;
s1 = 0.9/T;
s2 = 1.1/T;
b = fir1(400, [s1, s2]/fN, 'stop');
```

I don't use Octave any more, but on Matlab I got this filter response with `freqz(b)`:

[image]

To try downsampling the signal, you can try commands such as `downsample` and `resample` (again, from Matlab, but I seem to recall Octave has equivalents to these). Note that, even in this case, you may need to increase the order to obtain the kind of rejection you require.

Answer (score 2):

fir1 designs your filter using a Hamming window one bin larger than the degree you specify. 41 bins is too small to give you the frequency resolution you want. Try a much larger degree, say 300-600.